# Parse Duration String Java 7

Tags: java, date, parsing, duration

I want to parse Duration strings in Java 7, like **PT45M**. I try with SimpleDataFormat but not exist any pattern like PnDTnHnMn.nS. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

### ThreeTen Backport

As you may or may not be aware, and as the other answer says, the `Duration` class of java,time introduced in Java 8 can do that. The good news is that java.time has been backported to Java 6 and 7 too. Get the backport from the link at the bottom and go ahead. For example:

```
    System.out.println("Java version: " + System.getProperty("java.version"));

    Duration dur = Duration.parse("PT45M");

    System.out.println("Parsed duration: " + dur);
    System.out.println("Converted to whole seconds: " + dur.getSeconds());
```

On my computer output from this piece of code was:

> ```
> Java version: 1.7.0_67
> Parsed duration: PT45M
> Converted to whole seconds: 2700
> ```

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Java Documentation for Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html). You can convert that string to a duration object via parse method and get seconds with getSeconds() method. Then you can convert seconds to regular java DateTime API objects.

Comment: Hi Tuncer, thanks for the reply, but i have to do this with java 7 otherwise there were no problems.